# Kotlin import showing not used even though i am using it

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using these imports but its in the grey text so it's showing up as not used
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

```
button.setOnClickListener{
            times +=1
            **textView**.text= times.toString()
            Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "You klicked me!!!" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
```

The *`button`* and *`textView`* are errors
ps- I am new to kotlin and app dev

Comment: You can check these docs:
[Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button)  and
[TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)

Comment: what is `button` and `textView`? Are you using synthetics? Or declaring them by viewFindById, or using databinding?

Answer (score 1):

`Button` is not the same as `button`; `TextView` is not the same as `textView`. Using `Button` would be something like

```
val x: Button = ...
```

or

```
findViewById<Button>(...)
```

If you don't have those, the import is indeed not used and can be removed.

> The `button` and `textView` are errors

This is separate from imports not being used and the reason can't be seen without more of your code.